# How can I switch to window number greater than 10 or higher in Ratpoison?

Tags: ratpoison

The current list of the running windows can be shown by a ctrl/t+w .

Then I can switch to the window I want with ctrl/t + <0-9>.

However, I have more than 10 windows opened.

How could I switch to the tenth window?

Comment: Better answers as my self-answered one (particularly if they make it possible to switch to the >=10 windows directly) are welcomed and they are strong candidates for acception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to switch to windows >= 10 directly, at least not with an unpatched ratpoison with the default shortcuts.

However, you can switch to the next/previous windows by ctrl/t+n, ctrl/t+p . This cycle includes also the >= 10 windows.